# Is it necessary to sanitize pandasql queries when used on DataFrame objects

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, sanitization, pandasql

I have a simple app which loads a csv file into a DataFrame using pandas and proceeds to perform sql operations on it using pandasql. Some of these operations come from user input. For testing, I have the line

```
tempdb = sqldf('SELECT * from eventsdb_subset WHERE %s' % filterstring,locals())
```

where filterstring is raw user input. This is obviously a sql injection hole.

Usually when using databases like this you would sanitize user input, but in this case is there any need to? Because the DataFrame only exists in memory, files used are all local, and nothing is actually done to the csv file on disk, what harm could someone do with an unsanitized DB query that couldn't be solved by simply ignoring the output of that query?

EDIT: there's no question that this represents an SQL injection hole. My question is: if the DB only exists in local RAM, why do I care?

Comment: Can you do multiple/nested queries with pandasql ? That would be the hole right?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Yes, you could repeatedly query and whittle down the database that way, but there's no obvious problem with that. Doing two queries successively would be the same as to query1 AND query2 in one, no?

Comment: I think Andy is referring to someone writing a malicious query that involves many, many layers of nested operations which would consume system resources, effectively locking up whatever machine is running the program.